# gstreamer not found by CLion on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: c++, ubuntu, cmake, gstreamer, clion

I'm working on a project that requires gstreamer to stream a webcam feed over UPD to another computer. I've been trying all morning to get gstreamer installed on my Ubuntu 16.04, eventually I managed to get it working using the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install libgstreamer0.10-dev libgstreamer0.10-0-dbg libgstreamer0.10-0 gstreamer0.10-tools gstreamer-tools gstreamer0.10-doc gstreamer0.10-x
```

I also modified my cmake file in my project in an attempt to get the gstreamer library included (see comments):

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1.0)

PROJECT(gstreamer-test)

# paths
LINK_DIRECTORIES(/usr/local/lib)            # OpenCV
LINK_DIRECTORIES(/usr/include/glib-2.0)     #gstreamer
LINK_DIRECTORIES(/usr/include/gstreamer-0.10) 

# Build settings
SET(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH build/bin)
SET(LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH build/lib)
SET(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY build)


# Compiler settings
SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")


SET(OpenCV_LIBRARIES opencv_core opencv_highgui opencv_videoio -lopencv_calib3d opencv_imgproc -lopencv_imgcodecs opencv_ml opencv_objdetect opencv_features2d opencv_flann)


add_executable(gstreamer_test main.cpp)
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(gstreamer_test ${OpenCV_LIBRARIES})
```

Still, CLion refuses to include gstreamer. When I try to build the tutorial 'hello world' application from their website (https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/application-development/basics/helloworld.html), it fails because CLion cannot find the included gst/gst.h and glib.h files.

Some fora suggest using the find_package command, but I'm not even sure what the exact package name of this library is, I only know the location of the header files. Documentation about this seems to be scarce too.

Does anyone have an idea how to correctly include the gstreamer library in my project?

Comment: Why do you blame CLion, when it only calls `cmake`? And are you sure, `gst/gst.h` could be found by provided paths?

Comment: use `find_package` pattern

Comment: @user1056837 fair point, CLion can't help it. It's my lack of cmake knowledge. However, I am sure the paths /usr/include/gstreamer-0.10/gst/gst.h and /usr/include/glib-2.0/glib.h are correct.

Comment: @fandyushin I tried find_package(libgstreamer0.10-dev) but it cannot be found. I tried just entering 'gstreamer' too (and some other variations on the libgstreamer - name), but that didn't work either. Do you have any idea how I could identify the package name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `find_package`. You can take this module https://github.com/WebKit/webkit/blob/master/Source/cmake/FindGStreamer.cmake and put it e.g in ./cmake/ . Than add to your CMakeLists.txt

```
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/)

find_package(GStreamer)
if(GStreamer_FOUND)
  message(STATUS "FOUND!!")
  include_directories(${GSTREAMER_INCLUDE_DIRS})
endif()
...
target_link_libraries(gstreamer_test ${GSTREAMER_LIBRARIES})
```

My CMake output:

```
-- Found PkgConfig: /usr/bin/pkg-config (found version "0.29.1") 
-- Checking for module 'gstreamer-1.0 >= '
--   Found gstreamer-1.0 , version 1.8.3
-- Checking for module 'gstreamer-base-1.0 >= '
--   Found gstreamer-base-1.0 , version 1.8.3
-- Checking for module 'gstreamer-app-1.0 >= '
--   
-- Checking for module 'gstreamer-audio-1.0 >= '
```

And variables in CMakeCache:

```
//Path to a library.
GSTREAMER_LIBRARIES:FILEPATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstreamer-1.0.so
```

Comment: Thanks for the code. I put the FindGstreamer.cmake in the correct folder, added the code and reloaded the cmakefile. However, despite the libraries being found by cmake, the GSTREAMER_LIBRARIES variable is still 'set to notfound'. Here's the log:

-- FOUND!!
CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND.
Please set them or make sure they are set and tested correctly in the CMake files:
GSTREAMER_LIBRARIES (ADVANCED)
    linked by target "gstreamer_test" in directory /home/lorre851/CLionProjects/gstreamer-test

Comment: @LaurentLoots  this module using pkgconfig `find_package(PkgConfig)` . Do you have this package? `apt search pkgconfig` if not - unstall and try again, or you can search more simple module with out pkgconf.

Comment: yes, pkg-config is installed. The cmake log also displays de various gstreamer modules that are installed, so I guess that works fine

Comment: @LaurentLoots Fine! If you stuck with clion and buildin-cmake - try File->Invalidate Cache->Invalidate and restart. It helped me many times.

Comment: @LaurentLoots its looking for version 1.0, but you have 0.10. Change version in FindGStreamer.cmake file. Or install libgstreamer1.0

Comment: That did the trick! I swapped the FindGStreamer.cmake with the 0.10 version on https://github.com/adobe/webkit/blob/master/Source/cmake/FindGStreamer.cmake and now it works, thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1):

Just use `INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES` instead of `LINK_DIRECTORIES`

- The first stands for `-I` compiler option (where to find headers).
- The second - `-L` (where to find libraries).

As you understand it's different things.

Comment: I see. I used INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES, and now CLion doesn't choke on the #include statements anymore. However, when compiling, a lot of 'undefined reference' errors are being generated and the build fails.